# Spring HTTPS is switching to HTTP: I want to use either HTTPS or HTTP for the site depending on the user

Tags: java, spring, http, tomcat, https

I am using Spring 3, Java and Tomcat. We are using a load balancer that allows for HTTPS or HTTP requests. The problem is that the HTTPS requests are being converted to HTTP as soon as the login page is submitted.

The lock never displays in the browser bottom bar. I need the entire site to use either HTTPS or HTTP depending on the original request.

I have tried setting channel security in `security-config.xml` like this:

```
intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="any"
```

but no luck. If I set requires-channel="https" then I have to use HTTPS for the entire site but I want to let the user decide.

Thanks for any help. I have searched for days but can't find a solution.

Comment: Stupid question, but you double-checked that your form action points to https, correct?

Comment: action="/login_security_check" But I need https or http.

Comment: A login form should **never** point to http.  If you want the user to be able to use http after they login, you'll have to redirect from your https login action to another URL that uses http.

Comment: I am still stuck on this. I may need to try a different Spring view resolver to handle redirects. Help?

Comment: Can you add the entire security-config.xml to your original question above?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did although I was trying to force https all the time:

1. Create a custom header that the load balancer will append to the request denoting that it came through as https.
2. Write a servlet wrapper to override the `isSecure()` method looking for the https port as usual but also having the option to look for the header added by the load balancer.
3. Apply the wrapper with a filter in your filter chain .

This way the request is seen as secure and the redirect to http is not sent.